# Best practice regarding whether to check bin and obj into TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I always understood that best practice was never to check into TFS binary (e.g., bin and obj) files.
A while ago, someone in our implementation of TFS did not adhere to this, and checked in the bin and obj folders.
Thereafter, when I try to GLV code to a new machine, TFS downloaded all the project folders including items such as bin, obj, Debug etc and temp files like .dll, .cache, pdb. Then, when I run Clean Solution, TFS removes such files inside these folders, but then, when I Build, I get errors that there are dll files missing in obj\Debug folder.
To fix this, I then took the following steps:
I undid current changes so that TFS had nothing checked out.
I deleted the bin and obj folders from Source Control Explorer within TFS.
I checked it.
Such folders seemed to disappear from TFS, and I thought the problem was solved.

However, after that, when I GLV on the same machine, then Clean, then Build, then check-in recursively from the root of the TFS workspace, TFS automatically adds the dll’s and other extension like .cache files in those folders back into TFS! And we are back to square one.

So, should I try to prevent such files being checked in, or is there a way for all those files to be stored inside TFS without then causing me compilation errors??

Also, if best practice is to avoid checking in the bin and obj folders, how to I check in recursively from my local drive, after building, without checking in the bin and obj folders? Is there a way to exclude certain folder or file types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `.tfignore` file to the repo root so that those folders are not tracked by source control.

```
bin
obj
```

should be enough.